# How can I get grid-cell-collections from grid object?

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I iterate all grid-cell panels in currentPage from the top of panel widget object?

I cannot understand how to get cell-panel collections from grid object.

```
for (var cell in widget.decendants.MyGridWidget.???) {
    cell.decendants.somethingOperation;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup to hide all detail panels for a grid would be as follows:

GridPanel
Cell (i.e. children):

1. Header panel with a label widget and button widget (name: Button3).
   Set Button3 text to 'expand_less' initially.
2. Detail panel with three label widgets.

Code for onClick event for Button3:

```
var grid = widget.parent.parent.parent;
var cells = grid.children._values;
cells.forEach(function(i) {
  if(i.descendants.Button3.text === 'expand_less') {
    i.descendants.Button3.text = 'expand_more';
  } else {
    i.descendants.Button3.text = 'expand_less';
  }
});
```

Detail Panel visibility binding:

```
@widget.parent.descendants.Button3.text === 'expand_less'
```

Hope something like this will work for your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.
I intend to implement a funtion that not to toggle but to show/hide all detail panels.
According to your idea, I bind detail panel visibility to each toggle button caption as you say.
And I code for show button’s onClick forEach loop `i.descendants.Button3.text = ‘expand_less’;`
* the hide button can be implement in the same way.

Comment: You could actually implement an even easier solution. On top page panel scroll to the bottom of the editor to page properties. Set a boolean property, rename it 'ShowDetailPanel' or whatever suits you. Bind your detail panel visibility to '@widget.root.properties.ShowDetailPanel === null || @widget.root.properties.ShowDetailPanel'. For your button onClick event set it to: if(widget.root.properties.ShowDetailPanel === null || widget.root.properties.ShowDetailPanel) {widget.root.properties.ShowDetailPanel = false;} else {widget.root.properties.ShowDetailPanel = true;}

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following:

```
var cells = widget.children._values;
for (var i in cells) {
  console.log(cells[i].descendants._values[0].text);
}
```

In my example I set up a grid widget and for the widget onDataLoad event I reference the grid widget children and then iterate over all children, calling the first descendant of each cell and then logging the text.
This should probably get you in the right direction anyway. Depending on what you are trying to do with each descendant in a grid cell however, you may want to decide on binding each descendant instead or basing what you are trying to accomplish on the datasource item. Also, consider that descendants of a cell may be many elements, so you may need to iterate over each descendant as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I could implemented it with reference to your answer.

What I wanted to implement is below.

Each card widget consists of two panels.
One is a base panel, the second one is a details panel.
The details panel is toggled show/hide with the buttons placed on each card widget.
I wanted to create a function to show/hide the details panels of all the cards widget. 
I could get the cell widget of the grid, so it could implemented by controlling the visible property of those panels.

Comment: I see. Let me provide a new answer that will do just that. It will be a combination using a function on a button click event and using a binding on the detail panel visibility setting. Let me know if that will work for you.